# En este código javascript no encuentro el error en la lógica del condicional if

Tags: javascript, condiciones, validación

En este ejercicio de Javascript trato de validar la edades y hay algo que falla y es que el condicional no se comporta como debería según el rango de edad... ¿alguna sugerencia? ¿estará mal planteada la lógica? ¿Debería usar else if en vez de solo if?

me refiero a que si el usuario ingresa por ejemplo 20 años de edad, salta el mensaje "necesitas autorización de un adulto", por ejemplo.

```js
let edad = prompt("Ingresar edad");
    
    if (edad <= 6) {
        alert("No puede ingresar a la sala")
    }
    if (edad <= 13) {
        alert("Necesitas ingresar con un adulto/a");
    }
    if (edad >13){
        alert("Necesitas autorizacion de un adulto/a");
    }
    if (edad >= 18) {
        alert("Bienvenido al club")
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuá es el comportamiento esperado entonces?

Comment: Ten en consideración que el valor ingresado en el prompt es un string. Convierte la variable edad a número y vuelve a probar

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera estoy probando el codigo, y veo que funciona como se espera, lo que no queda claro, es el problema que el menciona. Dice que no se comporta, pero no menciona un caso de error.

Comment: :O habrá que esperar que el OP sea más claro con el problema. Gracias por la aclaración @Excorpion

Comment: me refiero a que si el usuario ingresa por ejemplo 20 años de edad, salta el mensaje "necesitas autorización de un adulto", por ejemplo

Comment: Tu condicional esta mal entonces... `if (edad >13)` Si la edad es mayor a 13... 20 es mayor a trece, si, salta... agregale otra condicion... `edad > 13 && edad < 18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Esta respuesta está basada en la idea de que solo espera mostrar un mensaje en cada rango de edades, por las respuestas que ha dado entiendo eso, pero podría no ser lo esperado***

Yo hubiera utilizado else-if. Te evita el rango superior. Si una no es válida, pasa a la siguiente ya con esa condición superada. Además, en cuanto una es válida deja de comprobar todo el resto de condiciones, mejorando ligeramente la eficiencia.

Otra cosa que mejora es que consigues que no muestre más de un mensaje. En el ejemplo, con un valor de 6 tu código te mostraría los dos primeros mensajes, ya que 6 es menor que 6 pero también menor que 13. No sé si tiene sentido eso en tu programa, habrá veces en que sí.

Por último, yo metería un casteo a número (con poner un + delante de la expresión te lo hace) por dejarlo más bonito. Sé que puede parecer que con que JS lo haga por detrás en cada comparación es suficiente, pero siempre es mejor tener el control de tu programa.

Ah, y usa const si no vas a cambiar el valor de una variable.

```js
const edad = +prompt("Ingresar edad");
    
if (edad <= 6) {
    alert("No puede ingresar a la sala")
} else if (edad <= 13) {
    alert("Necesitas ingresar con un adulto/a");
} else if (edad <= 17){
    alert("Necesitas autorizacion de un adulto/a");
} else {
    alert("Bienvenido al club")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basado en el comentario provisto por el OP

> me refiero a que si el usuario ingresa por ejemplo 20 años de edad, salta el mensaje "necesitas autorización de un adulto", por ejemplo

Para corregir el mal comportamiento, es solo corregir el 3er IF.
El cual solo consideraba un `edad > 13` siendo 20 mayor a 13... faltaba un limite superior, el cual es `edad < 18`

```js
let edad = prompt("Ingresar edad");

if (edad <= 6) {
  alert("No puede ingresar a la sala")
}
if (edad <= 13) {
  alert("Necesitas ingresar con un adulto/a");
}
if (edad > 13 && edad < 18) {
  alert("Necesitas autorizacion de un adulto/a");
}
if (edad >= 18) {
  alert("Bienvenido al club")
}
```

Comment: Si ingresas un número menor o igual que 6, aparecerán dos alertas. Habrá que esperar a ver si esto es lo que quiere OP.

Comment: En ese caso la corrección es similar, pero una vez preguntado el error de caso, el que menciona es el ya dicho, si el tiene o no otro comportamiento no esperado, es el quien lo debe mencionar, por que ya fue consultado 1 vez.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias de utilizar `if/elseif` para que la segunda y tercera condicion no se cumplan:

```js
  let edad = prompt("Ingresar edad");
    
    if (edad <= 6) {
        alert("No puede ingresar a la sala")
    }
    else if (edad <= 13) {
        alert("Necesitas ingresar con un adulto/a");
    }
    else if (edad < 18){
        alert("Necesitas autorizacion de un adulto/a");
    }
    else if (edad >= 18) {
        alert("Bienvenido al club")
    }
```

Comment: Esta respuesta supone un resultado y no sabemos cuál será ese resultado esperado

Comment: @Alfabravo tiraste -1 al post y la respuesta de una ? sin esperar un comentario al respecto ?

Comment: @Alfabravo no hay que ser tan metodico para entender lo que intenta hacer. Claramente hay un problema de logica donde si se cumple la segunda igual la tercera. Siquiera probaste el codigo?

Comment: Tan lo probé que cambié el bloque en la pregunta por un snippet. Pero no, el resultado esperado no está en la pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo VUELVO Y PREGUNTO: Realmente se necesita ser tan dotado para entender lo que el OP no logra hacer? Entiendo lo que quieres decir y veo que quieres que se cumplan las reglas pero ya a los niveles que lo quieres llevar son exagerados.

Comment: @Einer Pues, como lo acabo de obtener, puedo decir que tu respuesta es apresurada y no responde el problema del OP... el solo tenia malo el condicional del 3er IF... le faltaba otra condicion.

Comment: Leyendo los mensajes de las alertas, se puede suponer que la idea es que solo aparezca una y, por eso, esta respuesta me parece acertada.